# How to pass array of structures, which contain basic one | Polymorphism in Golang

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang and have a question below.

We have one basic structure and another two ones, which contain basic.
Is it possible to write a func, which expects an array of basic structure, but call that func with providing two other ones? See an example below.

```
// Pathable provide path property
type Pathable struct {
    path string
}

// File sturcture
type File struct {
    name string
    Pathable
}

// Directory structure
type Directory struct {
    name        string
    files       []File
    directories []Directory
    Pathable
}

// Detect if provided directories contain specified path
func ifPathAlreadyExist(entities []Pathable, path string) bool {
    for _, entity := range entities {
        if entity.path == path {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    pathables := []File{
        File{
            name: "some_file.txt",
            Pathable: Pathable{
                path: "test_path/to/file",
            },
        },
    }

    localPath := "some/path"
    if ifPathAlreadyExist(pathables, localPath) {
        fmt.Println("Exist")
    }
}
```

The code above throws an exception `cannot use pathables (variable of type []File) as []Pathable value in argument to ifPathAlreadyExist` on `ifPathAlreadyExist` call.

I suppose it's possible to create wrapper's funcs for each structure, which contains Pathable: those wrappers just convert provided array of structures to Pathable one and just call implemented `ifPathAlreadyExist` func above. But I feel like it's the wrong way.

So, actually my question is how to implement `ifPathAlreadyExist` in the right way, to avoid duplicating of that method for each structure, which contains `Pathable` structure inside?

Thanks for your attention and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [interfaces](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) for that. Here is [example](https://play.golang.org/p/9GwVRyBycav):

```
type Pathable interface {
    GetPath() (path string)
}

type PathableImpl struct {
    path string
}

func (p *PathableImpl) GetPath() string {
    return p.path
}

type File struct {
    name string
    PathableImpl
}

func printPaths(entities []Pathable) {
    for _, entity := range entities {
        fmt.Println(entity.GetPath())
    }
}

func main() {
    printPaths(
        []Pathable{
            &PathableImpl{path:"/pathableImpl"}, 
            &File{name: "file", PathableImpl: PathableImpl{path:"/file"}}
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got the idea of your code, but am I correct, if we have a slice of `File`, but not `Pathable`, we should convert it manually (through the loop?), before pass as param to `printPaths`?

Comment: @PavelSavushkin In example that i provided -- yes, because `File` itself doesn't implement `Pathable` interface, only pointer `*File` does, But you can change `GetPath` function signature to `func (p PathableImpl) GetPath() string`, then you can use `printPahts` for both `File` and `*File`. Beware, that this change of signature is ok for getter methods, but not for setters -- because function always receives copy of object as parameter,

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help - I'll try it out today's evening. Currently I have no opportunity to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is perfect usecase for go's [`interface`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces). Go doesn't provide you with an opportunity for unifying entities by it's internals, instead you can do it by its behaviour. 
So in your case there are just three different structs, and [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) `Pathable` to `File` doesn't make it `Pathable`, though `File` will inherit `Pathable` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, as you said and Grigoriy Mikhalkin provided an example, we should implement an accessor for `Pathable` struct and embed it into other ones. But as I understand, the function will expect exactly interface, but not struct. So, in that case I should manually implement conversion struct to interface slices, right?